# Creating stored procedure in SQL Server with single input variable that can only take specific integers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server which uses a single parameter (`@type`) which can only take integers 1 thru 4, which signify the type of a publication (cooking, psychology, business, computers) from a specific table.

Where in the stored procedure can I set the type to be 1 thru 4 based off the values in the type column of the table?

Hopefully I've provided enough details, but if not please let me know and I will add more.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the IF statement:

```
if @type = '1'
select data
from datatable
where type = 'cooking'

if @type = '2'
select data
from datatable
where type = 'psychology'
```

Comment: Ok, but the where clauses of your query seem to be incorrect (they should check a column, not your variable).

Comment: My mistake, it was late at night and I wrote my solution a little too quickly!  I've edited it, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Look into `case`. I saw this question last night and had no idea this is the behavior you wanted.